# Iterating over each cell in a column in Power Query

Tags: powerquery

I created a table called Table3 with two columns named URL which is empty and Value which contains a list of websites. The following query retrieves data from the websites stored in Table 3.

```
let
    Parameter = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
    URL= Parameter{1}[Value],
    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents(URL)),
    Data0 = Source{0}[Data],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Data0,{{"Date", type date}, {"Open", type number}, {"High", type number}, {"Low", type number}, {"Close", type number}, {"Volume", type number}, {"Market Cap", type number}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type",{"Market Cap", "Open", "High", "Low"}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Removed Columns",{{"Date", Order.Ascending}})
in
    #"Sorted Rows"
```

The second line runs the query for the first website in the Value column.

Is it possible to introduce a loop that would run the query for all the websites?

If not is it possible to run the query for all the websites in sequence by manually pasting the above code and changing the number in the brackets for each website?

If it is possible I assume it would load the contents in the same sheet, is there any way to load the content in different sheets for each iteration?

Thanks for reading my question.

Answer (score 2):

Loops aren't really a thing in Power Query, but you can still do what you're after. I don't know what URLs you're pulling from, so let me give you an example using publicly available ones.

---

Let's suppose my `Table3` is the following:

```
URL
--------
https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL?p=AAPL
https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL?p=GOOG
```

I can load this into the query editor and create a custom column that reads the webpage for each URL.

```
= Web.Page(Web.Contents([URL])){0}[Data]
```

(The table I want is the first one (hence the `{0}` row index) and is in the `[Data]` column.)

Now I have a table like this where the bottom table is a preview of the cell I have selected.

[image: Preview Table]

Click the arrows icon to expand the tables.

[image: Expand Tables]

From here you can filter `Column1` to pick which values you are interested in (let's say `Ask`, `Bid`, `Open`, and `Volume`) and then pivot that column (Transform > Pivot Column). Choose `Column2` as the values column and select "Don't Aggregate" under Advanced options.

[image: Pivot Column]

The result should be the table you see above the pivot dialogue box.

---

Here's the full M code for the query that shows up in the Advanced Editor

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"URL", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each Web.Page(Web.Contents([URL])){0}[Data]),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom", {"Column1", "Column2"}, {"Column1", "Column2"}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Expanded Custom", each ([Column1] = "Ask" or [Column1] = "Bid" or [Column1] = "Open" or [Column1] = "Volume")),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Filtered Rows", List.Distinct(#"Filtered Rows"[Column1]), "Column1", "Column2")
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```